# Probability of seeing multiple repetitions from sets of card draws

Tags: probability

My grasp of probability calculation is more than a little rusty, but I would like to have some actual numbers to back up a point. I start to get lost after adding in more than one 'at least' condition, but doing the calculations for this sort of question seems like it could be useful to me, and I'd greatly appreciate the help. So, here goes.

Say you have a deck of 78 unique cards, no duplicates. You randomly pull out 6 of those cards (no replacement, order doesn't matter). You make a note of the 6 that were drawn, and then replace all the cards. You then repeat this two more times, so that you now have 3 sets of 6 cards, each of which are your results of pulling with no replacement from an initially full deck of 78.

What is the chance of at least 2 cards showing up more than once? That is to say, if you were to combine the results of all 3 sets, what is the probability that at least 2 different cards have been repeated at least once in that list?

Comment: If the Queen of hearts is drawn in the first and third rounds, and no other card repeats,  have two cards repeated at least once? Or do we need to see  (for example) the Queen of hearts more than once, and the $5$ of diamonds more than once?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the latter example is what I'm looking for here, thanks for giving me the opportunity to clarify! I'd want to see the queen of hearts and the 5 of diamonds (or whichever) repeated, not just one card multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it like three draws from a $78/6$ lottery.
The first of the two or three draws between which comparisons are made can be anything.
If the second and third draws are to have no repeats, they will draw from a diminishing pool,
so # of ways $=\binom{72}{6}\binom{66}{6} = N_1$ (say)

If exactly one of $6$ numbers is to repeat,
either it could be in draws $1-2,\; 1-3,\; 2-3,\; $ or $1-2-3$
so # of ways = $6\left[3\binom{72}{5}\binom{67}{6} + \binom{72}{5}\binom{67}{5}\right] = N_2$ (say)

Unrestricted ways for second and third draws = $\binom{72}{6}\binom{72}{6} = D$ (say)

$Pr = 1 - \dfrac{N_1+N_2}{D}$